# Wind force not affecting hair particles

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

I have made a field of wheat using hair particles and I added wind. My windmill is affected by the wind but the wheat is not! How can I fix this?

I am sharing my wind and particle system options. I want my all objects to be affected by the wind.

These are screenshots of the particle system settings:

[image: screenshots 1]

| [image: screenshots 2] | [image: screenshots 3] |
| --- | --- |

And these are my wind settings:

[image: wind options]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if the wind force field and particle system objects (emitter and instances) are located on one 3D layer. It's likely they already are on one layer with the windmill

Comment: Thay are on the same layer look at this picture: https://image.prntscr.com/image/z0qtE2AlRIyX8MOiNQ5rhw.png

Comment: In [hair dynamics](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/hair/dynamics.html) turn down stiffness.

Comment: Possibly there's a checkoff in the "field weights" settings that enables forces?

Comment: i did turn down but just spring long time. not wind effect.

Comment: Yee your mean is here?
https://image.prntscr.com/image/WkroP5T-QIS6hJyiqHPuXw.png

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the Initial Orientation under Rotation from  "Object Y" to "Velocity/Hair".

[image: Settings for Rotation]

Keep your other numbers as they are; those in this image are for my particle system.

This will probably mean that your wheat will not stand up right. To fix that, select "Rotation" in the Render section. Then, if the wheat is still not standing up, try rotating your actual "Bugray" object by 90 degrees along first the X, then Y then Z axes.

[image]

Each time come back to your main layer with the particle system on it to check the effect, then if the wheat is still not upright, undo the previous rotation and try a different axis.

Eventually the wheat should stand up, and because it's rotation is following the hair, it should be affected by wind and other force fields.