# How to simulate lowpoly hair motion in wind

Tags: hair

[image]

all the tutorials I found were just flags

Comment: Somewhat related.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97408/how-to-get-wind-to-affect-hair-particles-with-group-or-object-render   I find google is a good search engine.  This search https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+hair+wind+tutorial came up with a number of other relevant links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For low poly hairs object ...

- go to *Weight Paint* mode and draw *Gradient* (from red on top)
- *Physics Properties* enable **Cloth**

[image]

- add **Wind** effector *Strength* 1000

[image]

- select *Head* go to *Physics Properties* enable *Collision*
  (better result with *Self Collision* enabled)

[image]